# Manjaro - Removing orphans resulted in problems

Tags: package-management, manjaro, pacman

I just wanted to remove orphan packages so I invoked the following command:

`sudo pacman -Rs $(pacman -Qqdt)`

Orphans where removed, but strangely it also removed further packages which still were needed by other packages or still where in use by me.
The most "dramatic" (I have noticed so far) is that now the letters in the terminal are overlapping:
[image: my terminal]

I could now reinstall all those packages. Is that the best way to go, in case something else is broken too? Or can I query if some packages are now missing some dependencies and reinstall those? This would definitely be a nicer way. In case one of you had the same issue, this where the packages that where uninstalled:

`brltty caribou chrome-gnome-shell dcadec exempi gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-arc-menu gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-dock gnome-shell-extension-gnomenu gnome-shell-extension-openweather gnome-shell-extension-taskbar gnome-shell-extension-topicons-plus gst-python gtksourceview2 js lib32-libtxc_dxtn libtxc_dxtn llvm manjaro-base-skel manjaro-gnome-extension-settings-17.0 nghttp2 noto-fonts-compat openjpeg pcaudiolib qt5-styleplugins qt5ct schroedinger ttf-hack xcursor-breeze xorg-fonts-misc`

Comment: Cannot really get why you do not install them, and try the process. That is where computers are good at.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Because I would install some packages which I do not need. What do you mean by "try the process"

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's why I asked if there is a pacman command to check if some packages are missing some of their dependencies and I appended the uninstalled packages in case someone had the same issue.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Dealing with packages is a learned skill via trial and error. Usually the package managers wont let you uninstall things that will let you in an inconsistent state. Usually. But I stress what packages are needed, and often how to deal with them depends on your needs, on the way you installed your system, and usually you learn all that with a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Reinstall that noto fonts package. This is the result of installing a distro that "makes Arch easier" by obscuring how Arch works from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've removed some font packages: `noto-fonts-compat`, `ttf-hack` and `xorg-fonts-misc`. All of these contain monospace fonts, and a terminal emulator normally uses a monospace font.

Without a screenshot of your terminal before the problem appeared, I cannot guess which font was used by your terminal window, but I'd bet it was in one of those three packages.

Now, when the actual font is gone but the settings of the terminal emulator (or any other program using that font) have not been changed, X11 does its best to find and use the "most similar" font it has available as a replacement. But the replacement-choosing algorithm only ensures that all the letters will fit into the space available for them; it cannot evaluate how good it will look.